# getting the current status of bootstrap switch in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I implemented bootstrap switch and changed the status to `Active` and `Inactive`. I wanted to capture the status of bootstrap switch after toggling in a table. But whenever I try to capture the status, it just shows `On` always. When bootstrap switch is toggled as `Inactive`, status should be captured as `off`, but it isn't happening.
JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/4erLr6ak/
**`HTML CODE:`**

```
<p class="lead">Multiple prices</p>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="text" id="type" name="type" value="" class="login password-field form-control" placeholder="Type of ticket" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <select class="form-control" id="multi">
    <option value="USD">$ USD</option>
    <option value="SGD">$ SGD</option>
    <option value="EUR">€ EUR</option>
    <option value="AUD">$ AUD</option>
    <option value="JPY">¥ JPY</option>
    <option value="CHN">¥ CHN</option>
    <option value="THB">฿ THB</option>
    <option value="MYR">RM MYR</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="number" id="ticketprice" name="price" value="" class="login password-field form-control" placeholder="Price of ticket" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" data-on-text="Active" data-off-text="Inactive" checked>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirm">Confirm</button>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered multtable" style="margin-top: 7%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Type of ticket</th>
      <th>Price of ticket</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**`Javascript code:`**

```
$('#confirm').click(function(e) {
  var type = $('#type').val();
  var currency = $("#multi option:selected").val();
  var mprice = $('#ticketprice').val();
  var status = $("[name='my-checkbox']").val();

  $('.multtable').append('<tr><td>' + type + '</td><td>' + currency + ' ' + mprice + '</td><td>' + status + '</td></tr>');

  /*Clear the values in text boxes after adding to table*/
  document.getElementById("type").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ticketprice").value = "";

  console.log(e);
})
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to check if the checkbox is checked use:

```
var status = $("[name='my-checkbox']").is(':checked');
```

instead of:

```
var status = $("[name='my-checkbox']").val();
```

you can use the true/false output to set your value accordingly